# How to anchor CategoryTextAnnotation at the top left of horizontal bar using JfreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have tired to figure this one out on my own and wondering if this is a known bug or a misunderstanding on my part of the jfreechart library.

I have two bars and want to display the text **"You"** and **"Neighboorhood avg."** In the top left corner of each bar. Similar to how it looks in the 2nd image.

What is the correct way to get both label position on the top left of the horizontal bar?

Here's the code that produced image 1:

```
   @RestController
public class JfreeCharCategoryAnnotationBug {

    @RequestMapping(value = "bug", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getBarChartWithCategoryAnnotationBug(String title) {
        DefaultCategoryDataset barDataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        String youDataKey = "You";
        String weDataKey = "Neightborhood Avg.";
        Map<TextAttribute, Object> values2X = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>();
        values2X.put(TextAttribute.KERNING, TextAttribute.KERNING_ON);
        values2X.put(TextAttribute.SIZE, 20);
        Font scaledFont = new Font("Arial Bold", Font.PLAIN, 20).deriveFont(values2X);
        barDataSet.setValue(200, youDataKey, youDataKey);
        barDataSet.setValue(2000, weDataKey,  weDataKey);
        JFreeChart barGraph = ChartFactory.createBarChart(null, "", "",
                barDataSet, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, false, false);
        Color weSpendColor = new Color(40, 137, 0);
        Color youSpendColor = new Color(48, 35, 174);

        // plot manipulations
        CategoryPlot plotModifier = barGraph.getCategoryPlot();
        barGraph.setBorderVisible(false);
        plotModifier.setOutlineVisible(false);
        // remove space between axis and data area
        plotModifier.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        plotModifier.setInsets(new RectangleInsets(0, 0, 0, 0), true);

        // Axis modifications
        ValueAxis rangeAxis = (ValueAxis) plotModifier.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setVisible(false);
        rangeAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
        CategoryAxis domainAxis = (CategoryAxis) plotModifier.getDomainAxis();
        domainAxis.setVisible(false);
        domainAxis.setAxisLineStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
        domainAxis.setLabelFont(scaledFont);

        // Actual data point manipulations
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plotModifier.getRenderer();
        renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
        renderer.setDrawBarOutline(true);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new CategoryItemLabelGenerator() {

            @Override
            public String generateRowLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int row) {
                return dataset.getRowKey(row).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public String generateLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int row,
                    int column) {
                Number value = dataset.getValue(row, column);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("$");
//                return sb.append(format(value.longValue())).toString();
                return sb.append(value.longValue()).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public String generateColumnLabel(CategoryDataset dataset,
                    int column) {
                return dataset.getColumnKey(column).toString();
            }
        });
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(scaledFont);

        // Color time
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, youSpendColor, true);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, weSpendColor, true);
        renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, youSpendColor, true);
        renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(1, weSpendColor, true);
        domainAxis.setAxisLinePaint(Color.GREEN);
        plotModifier.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);

        // margins and offsets
        renderer.setItemMargin(0);
        // for item label i.e $1K
        renderer.setItemLabelAnchorOffset(2);
        plotModifier.getDomainAxis().setCategoryMargin(0.0);
        // for space between the plot outline and the bar
        plotModifier.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0.30);
        plotModifier.getDomainAxis().setUpperMargin(0.0);
        plotModifier.getRangeAxis().setLowerMargin(0.0);
        // brings back some of the item text
        plotModifier.getRangeAxis().setUpperMargin(0.30);

//      annotations
        CategoryTextAnnotation we = new CategoryTextAnnotation(weDataKey,weDataKey, 0.0D);
        CategoryTextAnnotation you = new CategoryTextAnnotation(youDataKey,youDataKey, 0.0D);
        you.setFont(scaledFont);
        we.setFont(scaledFont);
        you.setPaint(new Color(135, 144, 153));
        we.setPaint(new Color(135, 144, 153));
        you.setCategoryAnchor(CategoryAnchor.START);
        we.setCategoryAnchor(CategoryAnchor.START);
        // possibly a jFreeChart bug Bottom_LEFT aligns first category's annotation to the position that TOP_LEFT should/does anchors the second category annotation 
        you.setTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
        we.setTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
        plotModifier.addAnnotation(you);
        plotModifier.addAnnotation(we);
        barGraph.removeLegend();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            // creating a chart with double the pixels for better rendering when client "auto layout" on mobile device 
            ChartUtilities.writeBufferedImageAsPNG(baos, barGraph.createBufferedImage(480,160, new ChartRenderingInfo()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //omitted 
        }
        MultiValueMap<String, String> responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);
        return new ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>(
                new StreamingResponseBody() {
                    @Override
                    public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                        baos.writeTo(outputStream);
                    }
                }, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}
```

Here's the code that produced image 2:

```
@RestController

public class JfreeCharCategoryAnnotationBug {

    @RequestMapping(value = "bug", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getBarChartWithCategoryAnnotationBug(String title) {
        DefaultCategoryDataset barDataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        String youDataKey = "You";
        String weDataKey = "Neightborhood Avg.";
        Map<TextAttribute, Object> values2X = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>();
        values2X.put(TextAttribute.KERNING, TextAttribute.KERNING_ON);
        values2X.put(TextAttribute.SIZE, 20);
        Font scaledFont = new Font("Arial Bold", Font.PLAIN, 20).deriveFont(values2X);
        barDataSet.setValue(200, youDataKey, youDataKey);
        barDataSet.setValue(2000, weDataKey,  weDataKey);
        JFreeChart barGraph = ChartFactory.createBarChart(null, "", "",
                barDataSet, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, false, false);
        Color weSpendColor = new Color(40, 137, 0);
        Color youSpendColor = new Color(48, 35, 174);

        // plot manipulations
        CategoryPlot plotModifier = barGraph.getCategoryPlot();
        barGraph.setBorderVisible(false);
        plotModifier.setOutlineVisible(false);
        // remove space between axis and data area
        plotModifier.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        plotModifier.setInsets(new RectangleInsets(0, 0, 0, 0), true);

        // Axis modifications
        ValueAxis rangeAxis = (ValueAxis) plotModifier.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setVisible(false);
        rangeAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
        CategoryAxis domainAxis = (CategoryAxis) plotModifier.getDomainAxis();
        domainAxis.setVisible(false);
        domainAxis.setAxisLineStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
        domainAxis.setLabelFont(scaledFont);

        // Actual data point manipulations
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plotModifier.getRenderer();
        renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
        renderer.setDrawBarOutline(true);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new CategoryItemLabelGenerator() {

            @Override
            public String generateRowLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int row) {
                return dataset.getRowKey(row).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public String generateLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int row,
                    int column) {
                Number value = dataset.getValue(row, column);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("$");
//                return sb.append(format(value.longValue())).toString();
                return sb.append(value.longValue()).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public String generateColumnLabel(CategoryDataset dataset,
                    int column) {
                return dataset.getColumnKey(column).toString();
            }
        });
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(scaledFont);

        // Color time
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, youSpendColor, true);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, weSpendColor, true);
        renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, youSpendColor, true);
        renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(1, weSpendColor, true);
        domainAxis.setAxisLinePaint(Color.GREEN);
        plotModifier.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);

        // margins and offsets
        renderer.setItemMargin(0);
        // for item label i.e $1K
        renderer.setItemLabelAnchorOffset(2);
        plotModifier.getDomainAxis().setCategoryMargin(0.0);
        // for space between the plot outline and the bar
        plotModifier.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0.30);
        plotModifier.getDomainAxis().setUpperMargin(0.0);
        plotModifier.getRangeAxis().setLowerMargin(0.0);
        // brings back some of the item text
        plotModifier.getRangeAxis().setUpperMargin(0.30);

//      annotations
        CategoryTextAnnotation we = new CategoryTextAnnotation(weDataKey,weDataKey, 0.0D);
        CategoryTextAnnotation you = new CategoryTextAnnotation(youDataKey,youDataKey, 0.0D);
        you.setFont(scaledFont);
        we.setFont(scaledFont);
        you.setPaint(new Color(135, 144, 153));
        we.setPaint(new Color(135, 144, 153));
        you.setCategoryAnchor(CategoryAnchor.START);
        we.setCategoryAnchor(CategoryAnchor.START);
        // possibly a jFreeChart bug Bottom_LEFT aligns first category's annotation to the position that TOP_LEFT should/does anchors the second category annotation 
        you.setTextAnchor(TextAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT);
        we.setTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
        plotModifier.addAnnotation(you);
        plotModifier.addAnnotation(we);
        barGraph.removeLegend();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            // creating a chart with double the pixels for better rendering when client "auto layout" on mobile device 
            ChartUtilities.writeBufferedImageAsPNG(baos, barGraph.createBufferedImage(480,160, new ChartRenderingInfo()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //omitted 
        }
        MultiValueMap<String, String> responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);
        return new ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>(
                new StreamingResponseBody() {
                    @Override
                    public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                        baos.writeTo(outputStream);
                    }
                }, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}
```

[image: With different TextAnchor]]

[image]

Comment: What versions of `JFreeChart` and `JCommon`?

Comment: @trashgod 1.0.19 & 1.0.23 respectively